# @ symbol in Peoplecode

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm trying to work out why it won't let me attach a file from a specific page in PeopleSoft CRM (it will show an error saying 'The AddAttachment() call failed.') while it does let me from the PeopleTools Test Utilities.

There seems to be a problem with the URL.

Looking at the traces, the lines that caught my attention the most are the following:

1. Correct trace from the PeopleTools Test Utilities:

> 22:       &RETCODE = AddAttachment(@(&URL_ID), &ATTACHSYSFILENAME,
>   &FILEEXTENSION, &ATTACHUSERFILE, &FILESIZE);
>
> ```
> EvalAddAttachment: processed URL catalog entry (on resume).
>
> IsURLValid: masked specified FTP URL = http://localhost:8230/psfiletransfer/demo/crm/
>
> GetLocalFilePath: temporary copy of file is /usrpsoft/demo/appserv/demo/files/psfileproc/A_de22a2f6-ffbf-11e0-8135-c80dfccab65c/borrador.txt
> ```

2. Trace from the pages that returns an error:

> 24:       &RETCODE = AddAttachment(&URL_ID, &ATTACHSYSFILENAME,
>   &FILEEXTENSION, &ATTACHUSERFILE, &FILESIZE);
>
> ```
> IsURLValid: masked specified FTP URL = http://localhost:8230/psfiletransfer/demo/crm/
>
> GetLocalFilePath: temporary copy of file is /usrpsoft/demo/appserv/demo/files/psfileproc/A_5da2dbaa-ffab-11e0-8135-c80dfccab65c/borrador.txt
> ```

**First of all,** what does the @ symbol mean in Peoplecode?

In the first trace, it appears right before the URL parameter. I went through the Peoplecode documents and I couldn't find it.

**And another thing:** the second line of the first trace won't appear in the second trace.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` symbol is used to dynamically refer to an object and in this case it is an URL.
The key is what is in the string `&URL_ID`.

If you use `@(&URL_ID)`, then `&URL_ID` should equal `URL.MY_URL`. If it is for a record, it would be something like `Record.MY_RECORD`, e.g. `&Rcd = GetRecord(@(&record));` or `&Rcd = GetRecord(@("Record."| Record.MY_RECORD));` or `&Rcd = GetRecord(@("Record.MY_RECORD"));`.

As for this "EvalAddAttachment" I'm not 100% sure. I wouldn't be too worried about it though. Just try to identify what is going into your variable (both the 1st and 2nd example) `&URL_ID.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a trace or throw in a messagebox and see what is being passed to the `&url_id`.  It should be equal to `URL.MY_URL` as posted above.

If the url format is that, then it has to do with some of your other variables that you are passing into the function.